# compare NSString using isEqualToString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsstring

Please, why doesn't `isEqualToString` work?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    extern NSString* globalpassword;

    if ([passwo.text isEqualToString: globalpassword]) {

        res = [[XMLTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"XMLTestViewController" bundle:nil];
        res.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self.view addSubview:res.view];
    } else {

        NSLog(@"faux");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"chikos" 
                                                        message:@"Wrong Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}


the result is                                      
2011-08-11 17:56:36.543 XMLTest[6389:207] pol
2011-08-11 17:56:36.544 XMLTest[6389:207] pol
2011-08-11 17:56:36.544 XMLTest[6389:207] faux
```

Comment: Why are you bothering with `stringWithString` instead of just doing `[passwo.text isEqualToString:globalpassword]` ?

Comment: i try to compare UIText filed and my globalpassord but not work

Comment: Edit your question and add some information on what's going wrong - is it crashing?

Comment: In your example there's not the two NSLog() calls that print 'pol'. Add the line like in my answer below, which'll show up any whitespace difference.

Comment: How is globalpassword being created? Want to make sure it has a retain count > 0.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your NSLog line; it should look like this :

```
NSLog(@"hi all freind");
```

(notice the @ sign!)

---

EDIT This must mean that you're ignoring your compiler warnings! They're there for a reason; in this case, telling you that you're passing in the wrong parameter to NSLog.

I bet you're also getting warnings on the `NSLog(cc)` and `NSLog(bb)` lines as well?

Comment: Actually, I like your answer better - the compiler can fix the bug I saw but it takes experience to fix the one you caught ;)

Comment: ok i correct them but i cant compare the value in my UITextFIled

Comment: What do you mean _can't_ - does it crash, does it give a compiler error, what's happening?

Comment: no but i have the same value in globalpassword and in my UITextFiled but the result for compare is false

Comment: If the result for compare is NO then you don't have the same value! How do you know that they are the same?

Answer (score 2):

The strings differ. Try logging bb and cc like this:

```
NSLog(@"bb: '%@', cc: '%@'", bb, cc);
```

With the single quotes you can see whether there is unexpected whitespace in either bb or cc.